# Foreign Key constraint error In Django

Tags: mysql, django

I am extending the Abstract user model in Django and it's not letting me migrate throwing an error related to the foreign key.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
import uuid

#Database model for Users.
class User(AbstractUser):
'''
    Abstract user model inherited containing all basic fields such as:
    first and last name, username, email, password etc. Abstract User fields. 
'''
    user_id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key = True, 
        default = uuid.uuid4, 
        editable = False
        )
    is_owner = models.BooleanField(
    default = False
    )



    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Users'

    def __str__(self):
         self.constructLabel(
            self.first_name, 
            self.last_name,
            self.user_id
        )
```

The error : 
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1215, 'Cannot add foreign key constraint')

From the database error is:

```
2017-04-09 20:33:07 0x7f3440171700 Error in foreign key constraint of table shipapp/#sql-3c9_33:
 FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users_user` (`user_id`):
Cannot resolve table name close to:
 (`user_id`)
```

Can anybody who has faced this before help me out? I have been out of touch since Django 1.8.5 was released. :(

Comment: what is shipapp here ? Post your full traceback

Comment: shipapp is my project name.

Comment: Please post your full traceback. One thing, error is related to `add foreign key` .In your code you posted, there is no foreign key.

Comment: I checked everything. And found the problem. I am pointing the solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem at least although it's not a recommended way to solve this although the solution might be specific to my problem. As I had just started making the models I could afford to re-initialise the whole project and copy the models and make migrations again. 
The problem was I think in the initial migration files that were created and after repeatedly deleting and recreating the files the error still arose from those initial files.

The lesson to be learned from this and the things I did wrong was:

**Mistakes :**

1. I made multiple models based on the E-R diagram I had made concurrently.
2. I did not migrate while I made all of them.
3. Made all of the relations at the same time.
4. Tried to migrate them at once and there arose a race condition of a
   kind. Every relation was attempted while making the model. I read
   somewhere where a guy had quoted "You can't eat the pastry while
   still keeping it with yourself."

**What I should have done:**

1. Made the models one by one.
2. Migrated the models keeping them atomic ie: without the relations
   between them. Keep only non-relation fields.
3. After migrating the models, write out the relations between the
   models.
4. Then migrate the models with the relations between them.